# UIAlertView Show causing strange behavior with UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibutton, uialertview

I basically have a replica of the iMessage app, but I am getting a strange behavior that the Send button is reverting back to the down position (When keyboard now showing), when I present a UIAlertView.

If I comment out [alert show], the Send button doesn't disappear.

If I do [alert show] the UIButton disappears behind the keyboard.

In the `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` I can press the cancelButton which causes no code in the method to execute, and the button will still disappear.

The only way I can get it to maintain its position is to manually put it back in that position in the `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`. There is no code about the Send UIButton either in any of the UIAlertView delegate methods except when I manually set it's frame back to the correct position.

Is this just a bug in iOS7 or is it something I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I got the same problem here with the above case. Seems a bug with iOS7, but your way around worked, though it seems weird that button disappears for few secs.

Comment: @Vacca yea... I am not sure what is going on with that.